# Calling methods dynamically (Crystal-lang)

Tags: crystal-lang

I understand that this may be a duplicate of [Any equivalent of Ruby's public_send method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48521444/any-equivalent-of-rubys-public-send-method). I'd like to explain what I am doing, and perhaps someone could advice.

I've been porting a ruby app over the last few days to learn Crystal. I've had to cut out a lot of functionality due to lack of `send` but today I've hit a main artery in my program.

I have a Hash which contains keystroke as key, and method as value. Based on what key is struck, the appropriate method is called. This obviously uses the `send` to implement the same.

From the linked question, I understand that Crystal is compiled so dynamic method calls are not permitted. However, if you look at the Vim editor, a user can map keys to methods, too. And vi(m) is written in C.

I am wondering if I missed something.

I know I could probably hardcode a switch statement with each key and call the appropriate method, but that still does not allow the user to assign a key to a method. Is there any alternative to this very large switch-case method ?

(I am guessing that rather than check the key in the `when` part, I would check the binding and call the method.

```
 binding = @bindings[key]
 case binding
 when :up
    up
 when :down
    down
 when .....
 else
 end
```

Any better solution ?

Comment: Clarifying your Vim example - I would guess Vimscript is what is handling key bindings, which is a dynamic language. If it was going through C, they could have a mapping of key to function and lookup the method from that.

Comment: In C this maps trivially to a function pointer. The functions are all compiled already, and the calling code too, and the changing input value merely selects which function to use by  referring to it's location in memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that this way most simple and convenient (perhaps more experienced developers will correct me below) but i would use the [Proc](https://crystal-lang.org/reference/syntax_and_semantics/literals/proc.html):

```
def method1
  puts "i'm  method1"
end

def method2
  puts "i'm method2"
end

def method3
  puts "i'm  method3"
end

hash = { 
  "ctrl":  -> { method1 },
  "shift": -> { method2 },
  "alt":   -> { method3 }
}

binding = ["ctrl", "shift", "alt"].sample
hash[binding].call #=> i'm method2
```

See [working example](https://carc.in/#/r/6t9o)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works. I'll mark it as the correct answer if nothing better comes up. I wish someone had mentioned this in the linked question.

Comment: I'll just put in a little note. Crystal unlike Ruby can't modify its code during execution, after compilation process code represents is just low level instructions. In running Ruby `send` can find in the class hierarchy required method and call him. Crystal code has no classes, methods or another objects familiar to us, there is simply nothing to call.

Comment: But the Crystal has wonderful macros that allow emulate a lot of things that we are used to in interpretable languages. For example Crystal can find instance variables and make anything with it. This article helped me to understand the concept: https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/wiki/Metaprogramming-Help

Comment: A note regarding the specific use case: A common idiom to implement configurable user input like key bindings is to use a mapping from key to an internal identifier (for example `"ctrl+c" => "clipboard.copy"`). These internal identifiers can be hard coded into the program (for example used in a `switch`) while their mappings can be changed.

Comment: The suggestion by @JohannesMüller sounds like the hardcoded example I had put in my question. Is that right, Johannes ?